# How to write text inside circle near border using shape outside?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to write text or add icons near border circle div tag. 
[image: like this] Is someone have do this idea. I am try do this last one week but cannot do

Comment: You have to use positions cause this is not following a regular structure.

Comment: Please post your html and css

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use position:absolute property with top, left, right, bottom with all the child elements of parent

Comment: Please write css code

Comment: This is not a good answer.  Not my downvotes.  IN such a situation, its best to use the comment to ask more questions first.